# R corrplot: Plot correlation coefficients along with significance stars?

Tags: r, correlation, significance

Using R corrplot, I have not found a solution where the correlation coefficients in the boxes are plotted together with their significances, i.e. 0.84***
Here is the code plotting only the significance stars. How can the correlation coefficients be added there?

```
M<-cor(mtcars)
res1 <- cor.mtest(mtcars, conf.level = .95)
corrplot(cor(mtcars),
     method="square",
     type="lower",
     p.mat = res1$p,
     insig = "label_sig",
     sig.level = c(.001, .01, .05),
     pch.cex = 0.8,
     pch.col = "red",
     tl.col="black",
     tl.cex=1,
     outline=TRUE)
```

If I add, as by the first answer suggested, addCoef.col = "black",
the text overlays the significance stars so they cannot really be seen anymore:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The position of the significance stars is defined by the `place_points` function within the `corrplot` function.

### **Problem:**

If both, the correlation coefficients and the significance level should be displayed, they overlap (I took yellow for the stars since I have some issues with colour vision...).

```r
library(corrplot)
#> corrplot 0.90 loaded

M<-cor(mtcars)
res1 <- cor.mtest(mtcars, conf.level = .95)

corrplot(cor(mtcars),
         method="square",
         type="lower",
         p.mat = res1$p,
         insig = "label_sig",
         sig.level = c(.001, .01, .05),
         pch.cex = 0.8,
         pch.col = "yellow",
         tl.col="black",
         tl.cex=1,
         addCoef.col = "black",
         tl.pos="n",
         outline=TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

### Quick and temporary (you have to re-do this step everytime you newly loaded the corrplot package) solution:

Change the `place_points` function within the `corrplot` function. To do so, run:

```
trace(corrplot, edit=TRUE)
```

Then replace on line 443

```
place_points = function(sig.locs, point) {
  text(pos.pNew[, 1][sig.locs], pos.pNew[, 2][sig.locs], 
       labels = point, col = pch.col, cex = pch.cex, 
       lwd = 2)
```

with:

```
# adjust text(X,Y ...) according to your needs, here +0.25 is added to the Y-position    
place_points = function(sig.locs, point) {
      text(pos.pNew[, 1][sig.locs], (pos.pNew[, 2][sig.locs])+0.25, 
           labels = point, col = pch.col, cex = pch.cex, 
           lwd = 2)
```

and then hit the "Save" button.

### Result:

```r
library(corrplot)
#> corrplot 0.90 loaded

#change the corrplot function as described above 
trace(corrplot, edit=TRUE)
#> Tracing function "corrplot" in package "corrplot"
#> [1] "corrplot"

M<-cor(mtcars)
res1 <- cor.mtest(mtcars, conf.level = .95)

corrplot(cor(mtcars),
         method="square",
         type="lower",
         p.mat = res1$p,
         insig = "label_sig",
         sig.level = c(.001, .01, .05),
         pch.cex = 0.8,
         pch.col = "yellow",
         tl.col="black",
         tl.cex=1,
         addCoef.col = "black",
         tl.pos="n",
         outline=TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-10-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: the variable names are not displayed anymore...any fix to this?

Comment: @Olympia. Just replace `tl.pos="n"` with `tl.pos="ld"`. See specific labeling [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html#change-color-spectra-color-legend-and-text-legend)

Comment: glad to hear. did this solve your question now?

Comment: yes, thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

You only have to add the option `addCoef.col = "black"` to `corrplot`

Comment: The problem with this is that now the text of the correlation coefficient overlays the significance stars...any solution for that?

Comment: I'm not sure that is possible, maybe you can mix significance level starts below diagonal and coefficients upper diagonal. Have you look at here: http://jamesmarquezportfolio.com/correlation_matrices_in_r.html?

Answer (score 1):

To fix the colour clash of the stars I adapted this approach to have bigger stars with a white colour. I use this with the following colours and layout. I can't avoid the overlap but it is legible enough for me to work with:

```
cex.before <- par("cex")
par(cex = 0.7)
col <- colorRampPalette(c("#BB4444", "#EE9988", "#FFFFFF", "#77AADD", "#4477AA"))
corrplot::corrplot(cor(mtcars), 
    method="color", 
    col=col(200),  
    type="lower", 
    # Combine with significance
    p.mat = res1$p, 
    insig = "label_sig",
    sig.level = c(.001, .01, .05), 
    pch.cex = 3, # Increase size of stars
    pch.col = "white", # Colour of stars
    # hide correlation coefficient on the principal diagonal
    diag=FALSE,
    addCoef.col = "black", # Add coefficient of correlation
    tl.col="black", tl.srt=45, #Text label color and rotation
    tl.cex = 1/par("cex"), cl.cex = 1/par("cex") #Reduce text size of coefficients               
)
par(cex = cex.before)
```