# Annotate corrplot coefficient and significance without overlapping

Tags: r, r-corrplot

Is there a way to add the coefficient and the significance to the same correlation triangle using the [CORRPLOT package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=corrplot), without the two overlapping, as in the figure below.

[image: Example graphic, x vs y matrix with color coding]

this is the code i used:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(corrplot)


dados <- read.table("Planilhacorre.txt",
                    na.strings = "NA",h=TRUE)

dados <- drop_na(dados)
matrix_corr <- cor(dados)

res1 <- cor.mtest(matrix_corr, conf.level = .95)
corrplot(matrix_corr, p.mat = res1$p, method = "color", diag = T, type = "lower",sig.level = c(.01, .05), pch.cex = 1, insig = "label_sig", pch.col = "red", order = "original",addCoef.col ='black',
tl.cex = 1, tl.col = "black",tl.srt = 1,
number.cex= .8)
```

Comment: Provide example data, or use existing example data - mtcars. And your current codes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R corrplot: Plot correlation coefficients along with significance stars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227830/r-corrplot-plot-correlation-coefficients-along-with-significance-stars)